# Unity Control object with a script that is controlled with an attached script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed a tutorial on making the Tron game for my project and I want to add multiplayer capability. I've set up a message system where a phone sends a direction change to the computer displaying the game to then make their player change direction. Each player is controlled with an attached 'Move' script that uses references to itself and a set of methods based on key inputs. I'm trying to get my game manager to receive these messages from the phone and cause the players to switch direction - I've tried making the move script have static elements but that seems to break it.

Is there a good way of doing this or would it be preferable to write a new move script that controls all players simultaneously that is just attached elsewhere?

The current code is as follows:

```
switch (direction)
            {
                case "N":
                    Instance.player1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.up * Move.speed;

                    break;
                case "E":
                    Instance.player1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * Move.speed;

                    break;
                case "S":
                    Instance.player1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.down * Move.speed;

                    break;
                case "W":
                    Instance.player1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.left * Move.speed;

                    break;
```

Move is a reference to the script attached to each game, but for the script to function, a call to this method is required after each direction change:

```
public void spawnWall()
{
    lastWallEnd = transform.position;
    GameObject objectOfGame = (GameObject)Instantiate(wallPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    wall = objectOfGame.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}
```

I tried to make it static but it wasn't working so I'm guessing that's not the route to take. SpawnWall is called every time an internal direction change is made.

```
void createConstantWall(Collider2D collision, Vector2 start, Vector2 finish)
{
    collision.transform.position = start + (finish - start) * 0.5f;
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(start, finish);
    if (start.x != finish.x)
        collision.transform.localScale = new Vector2(distance + 1, 1);
    else
        collision.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, distance + 1);
}
```

This function is called in update

Losing method:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision != wall)
    {
        //add losing stuff
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using statics, and why? If there are different players with the same move scripts on them, using a static value in any of those scripts will not work.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Yeah I figured that so I've removed pretty much all the static stuff to do with it.

Comment: So your problem is "How do I control different players separately, if the inputs are from phones?"

Comment: My question is: is there a way to access a script that is attached to separate players from another script and cause it to do things to individual players with their individual scripts, and if there is a such a thing, would it be preferable to use it or just recreate the move script in a more general place that controls all players with one script not attached to any individual player.

Comment: You can have a script that accesses separate players and there are a few ways to do this. You could configure your input manager to take input from a designated controller, but if phones are your "controller", then you'll probably want to create an input manager. I'll write up something briefly.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Just a note, the phone has 4 arrows on it, when one is pressed, a custom message is sent through the game manager and client script depicting the player number and direction into the server script  which then receives it, creates some case statements that breaks down what to do depending on the player number and direction given. I'm using lidgren to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle multiple user inputs from different phones (or other sources). Here is my preferred solution:

- All input goes through a generic manager with the player's id whenever movement is sent. This input is converted to an event to simplify dependencies.

Since you have stated you already have a custom message being sent to the game manager with the player number and direction, we will work with that.

Within your GameManager.cs or an InputManager.cs

```
public static event Action<int, string> OnInputReceived;

void InputReceived(int playerNumber, string direction)
{
    OnInputReceived?.Invoke(playerNumber, direction);
}
```

Within your PlayerMovementController.cs that should be attached to each individual player in the game, you should be tracking your playerId, or be able to check another attached script for the playerId:

```
public int playerId;

void Awake()
{
    GameManager.OnInputReceived += MovePlayer;
}

void MovePlayer(int inputPlayerId, string direction)
{
    if(inputPlayerId != playerId)
        return;
    else
    {
        //move THIS player in the "direction" using your movement logic
    }
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    GameManager.OnInputReceived -= MovePlayer;
}
```

If all of your players have unique ids and have the PlayerMovementController attached, they can now all listen to the inputs but only move when their ID is tied to it. If your GameManager calls InputReceived(1,"E"), all of your PlayerMovementControllers will call MovePlayer(1, "E"), but only the one with playerId == 1 will actually move since all of the others return immediately.

-- Diclaimer: All of this code is freehanded in StackOverflow, so there may be some syntax errors I didn't catch. Please let me know or edit it directly.

Comment: Just checking, in the first manager code bit, is the line within the InputReceived method where it says "OnMovementInput?" meant to be OnInputReceived or is it referencing something else?

Comment: You are correct! I'll fix that. I changed my mind on what to call it :)

Comment: Hmm, the control seems to be working but it's made the same problem as I previously had when testing out statics. The methods responsible for making the wall behind the player as per Tron is not functioning as it should be. I made a gif of the problem: https://gyazo.com/cda97076ce87491537d5a0d2e3a20f44

Comment: That problem is not related to statics or your movement logic that I can see. Can you include more information about your wall logic in your question? It looks like your code isn't creating a new wall when direction changes.

Comment: It's probably easier just to link you to the tutorial I used: https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-tron-lightcycles-game I didn't really deviate from it much

Comment: It's weird because after removing all the static experimenting I did, it went back to working, could it be due to something where it only works because the movement updates are in the update function along with the SpawnWall and createConstantWall methods

Comment: It's probably because your wall method is not listening to the same input. I would recommend moving your spawn wall logic to a different script and listen to movement changes on the same OnInputReceived event.

Comment: Right I realised that I forgot to make my spawnWall method unstatic again which fixes the previous error, so I did that, now whenever an input comes in, the player does it, then instantly dies. Not entirely sure why, I'll attach my death script in the first post.

Comment: my debugging has found that it's apparently colliding with the wall clone being set up behind it

Comment: did you fix your issue with colliding with the wall? There's a few ways to fix it, the most notable one being to delay enabling the collider for a few frames to let the player get out. @DomBeasley

Comment: I started another post here to address it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652406/unity-object-collides-with-clone-created-behind-it-despite-supposedly-not-being