# Unity object collides with clone created behind it despite supposedly not being affected by it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have followed this tutorial to make a tron game: https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-tron-lightcycles-game
and then attempted to add multiplayer capability using this

```
void MovePlayer(int inputPlayerId, string direction)
{
    Debug.Log("Attempting Move on " + inputPlayerId + " " + direction);
    if (inputPlayerId != playerId)
        return;
    else
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case "N":
                Debug.Log("moving up");
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.up * speed;
                spawnWall();
                break;
            case "E":
                Debug.Log("moving right");
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
                spawnWall();
                break;
            case "S":
                Debug.Log("moving down");
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = -Vector2.up * speed;
                spawnWall();
                break;
            case "W":
                Debug.Log("moving left");
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = -Vector2.right * speed;
                spawnWall();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

which is called every time a message is sent from the phone (client) through to the server which is displaying the game and changes the direction of each player.

However in doing so I seem to have broken the regular function of the game:

```
public void spawnWall()
{
    lastWallEnd = transform.position;
    GameObject objectOfGame = (GameObject)Instantiate(wallPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    wall = objectOfGame.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

void createConstantWall(Collider2D collision, Vector2 start, Vector2 finish)
{
    collision.transform.position = start + (finish - start) * 0.5f;
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(start, finish);
    if (start.x != finish.x)
        collision.transform.localScale = new Vector2(distance + 1, 1);
    else
        collision.transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, distance + 1);
}
```

These two functions are responsible for creating a wall that follows the first object to create the basis of Tron. Then in the death check method here:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision != wall)
    {
        Debug.Log("deading because of " + collision.name);
        //add losing stuff
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

it prevents it from colliding with the wall. However, now whenever an input is received, the action will happen for a very short time then apparently collide with one of the cloned objects behind it.

I tried delaying the spawnWall function to no avail, it just did this if delayed any longer than 0.3 seconds:

[image]

The createConstantWall method is called within update. The MovePlayer method is called whenever an input is received from the client.

Comment: Your `SpawnWall` method always spawns a wall directly on top of the player, not behind them. On top of that, there are two update cycles, `Update` (every graphical render frame) and `FixedUpdate` (every physics update frame; collissions are always processed in the FixedUpdate cycle).

Comment: Can you show the game scene with the size of the colliders shown?

Comment: I added a delay on the collider check each time spawnwall is called and it seems to be working fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a variable that stops the collision check from being called that gets enabled every time the spawnWall method is called for a second seems to have fixed it.